# thymeleaf round formatDecimal

Tags: thymeleaf, rounding

I want to round a number, which is
[image]

**0.047518320381641387939453125(now)  ---->   0.05(expected)**

but I used the following function,

[image]

only got the result

```
.00
```

Could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
${#numbers.formatDecimal(content.number == null ? 0 : content.number, 0, 0)}
```

This is working for me.

Comment: The 2nd parameter of formatDecimal defines the minimum number of digits before the delimiter. Thus, the questioner is getting ".XX". So also change the 2nd parameter to 1 for a nicer output.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the data type of data.userdSpace is the Integer.

If you change Integer to Double, it will work.