# format number on thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, number-formatting

I am trying to format number in thymeleaf, but all my attempts are not working.

```
<td class="text-right" th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(T(Math).rint(2.6),0,'COMMA')}"></td>

<td class="text-right" th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(2.6,0,'COMMA')}"></td>
```

This is what I want

```
2.1 -->2
 2.5-->3
12.50 -->13
12.49 -->12
```

I don't want to use number format on controller to format number. I want something that I can do on html itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884509/thymeleaf-round-formatdecimal?rq=1

Comment: i want 2.5 to be converted to 3. but this is converting to 2.

Answer (score 1):

The rounding mode for `#numbers` appears to match the default (which is HALF_EVEN -- and why you're seeing 2.5 -> 2).  If you want to control the rounding mode, this will give you the correct rounding:

```
<span th:text="${new java.math.BigDecimal(2.5).setScale(0, T(java.math.BigDecimal).ROUND_HALF_UP)}" />
```